# Convergence of improper integrals and Cauchy Principal Value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let us consider $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f$$

We can either calculate the ordinary value by $$\lim_{r\to \infty}\int_c^rf + \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{-r}^c$$

OR we can calculate the Cauchy Principal Value by ;

$$\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_{-r}^{r}f$$

Now We know that if CPV and Ordinary Value both converge, it's the same value.
But There are cases when CPV converges but the Ordinary Value does not?

In such cases, what do we say? Do we say that integral is divergent? Or if CPV converges do we directly conclude that the integral is convergent? And why?

Comment: Hint ::::: f(x)=x

Comment: yes sorry about that

Comment: Integral exists $\implies$ CPV exists (by definition). But CPV exists $\not\implies$ integral exists ($f(x) = x$ as mentioned above is a standard counter-example). If the integral does not exist then it's called a divergent integral regardless of if the CPV exists or not.